# Yii CGridView - What AJAX response is expected?

Tags: php, gridview, yii

The `CGridView` component has an `ajaxUrl` property. I don't fully understand what kind of response is expected from the url. Is it a rendered HTML to replace the existing component? Is it JSON data or the dataprovider?

EDIT: Or are we expected to manually implement a data handler?

Answer (score 2):

This is some HTML corresponding to the CGridView. For example in the controller you could put:

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
    $this->renderPartial('_yourGridView',array(
            'model' => $model,
    ));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Where `_yourGridView` is a view containing my CGridView widgets

Note also that the ajaxUrl is necessary only if the url is different than the current one.
If you want to use the same url (so the same controller and the same action) you don't have to specify it

Comment: So the response should be generated gridview HTML? That sounds inefficient.

Comment: Yes it does! 
And in gii's generated controllers it's even worse, because it's rendering the whole page! That is the reason why some people created an extension "yii-booster" where you have the possibility to give some JSon to a CGridView: http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/json-grid.html